# Copying data from one row to another in the same column based on another column not being NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a issue with a table that has missing data from some rows, I need to copy the Artist column from another row that matches on title

```
Plays |  Title                   |  Artist
------+--------------------------+----------------
107   |  Superstition            |  Stevie Wonder
96    |  Superstition            |  NULL
158   |  Patience                |  Guns n Roses
9     |  Patience                |  NULL
112   |  Promised You A Miracle  |  Simple Minds
99    |  Promised You A Miracle  |  NULL
159   |  Baker Street            |  Gerry Rafferty
132   |  Baker Street            |  NULL
```

I have read a bunch of other questions on SO's that has landed me with this UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE MetaDataTable
SET Artist = (SELECT TOP 1 Artist FROM MetaDataTable t 
              WHERE (Title = t.Title) AND t.Artist IS NOT NULL)
WHERE Artist IS NULL
```

What this end up with is the TOP 1 Artist being copied to all NULL Artist columns, not the Artist with the matching Title.

```
Plays |  Title                   |  Artist
------+--------------------------+----------------
107   |  Superstition            |  Stevie Wonder
96    |  Superstition            |  Stevie Wonder
158   |  Patience                |  Guns n Roses
9     |  Patience                |  Stevie Wonder
112   |  Promised You A Miracle  |  Simple Minds
99    |  Promised You A Miracle  |  Stevie Wonder
159   |  Baker Street            |  Gerry Rafferty
132   |  Baker Street            |  Stevie Wonder
```

What I would like is this:

```
Plays |  Title                   |  Artist
------+--------------------------+----------------
107   |  Superstition            |  Stevie Wonder
96    |  Superstition            |  Stevie Wonder
158   |  Patience                |  Guns n Roses
9     |  Patience                |  Guns n Roses
112   |  Promised You A Miracle  |  Simple Minds
99    |  Promised You A Miracle  |  Simple Minds
159   |  Baker Street            |  Gerry Rafferty
132   |  Baker Street            |  Gerry Rafferty
```

The rows with NULL Artist could be anywhere in the table and are not strictly below a complete row with the same Title.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to table qualify your `title` column since both tables are the same. `Title = t.Title` is the same as `t.Title = t.Title` because the closest matching column is the table in the sub-query, not the table being updated. Change it to `MetaDataTable.Title = t.title`.

```
UPDATE MetaDataTable
   SET Artist = (SELECT TOP 1 Artist FROM MetaDataTable t WHERE MetaDataTable.Title = t.Title AND t.Artist IS NOT NULL)
WHERE Artist IS NULL
```

Comment: Ok, that works! I am sure I tried that but was getting an error, but it has just run have updated the test table correctly!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest an updatable CTE:

```
WITH toupdate as (
      SELECT mdt.*,
             MAX(mdt.artist) OVER (PARTITION BY mdt.title) as imputed_artist
      FROM MetaDataTable mdt
     )
UPDATE toupdate
   SET Artist = imputed_artist
WHERE Artist IS NULL;
```